# How to delete an existing column with Not Null constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I have a table `Employee`. I want to delete the `Starting Date` and `Ending Date` columns. Initially, `Not Null` constraints were assigned to them. Then I changed to `Null`.

But whenever I am trying to delete these two columns, I am getting an error.
Please see the screenshot and help me execute the task.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, drop the constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT NameYourConstraint;
```

If you don't now the names:

```
SELECT *
FROM [sys].[default_constraints]
WHERE [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Employee]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the contrainsts first -

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Employee__Starti__47DBAE45;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Employee__Ending__5AEE82B9;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP COLUMN StartingDate;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP COLUMN EndingDate;
```